# I am using it in my m.phil research so it is very vital for me to Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\Gamma(n/2+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, gamma-function

I want to sum the following:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\Gamma(n/2+2)}$$

Comment: Please read the guidelines shown to you prior to asking the question, to avoid getting downvoted

Comment: In particular, what have you tried ? Or what are your initial thoughts ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are aware of the incomplete gamma function,
$$\sum_{x=0}^n \frac{1}{\Gamma \left(\frac{x}{2}+2\right)}=-\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}+e\, \text{erfc}(1)\right)+\frac{e \,\Gamma \left(\frac{n+4}{2},1\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+4}{2}\right)}+\frac{e\, \Gamma \left(\frac{n+3}{2},1\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)}$$ When $n\to \infty$, the sum of the last two terms tend to $2e$ and this makes
$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma \left(\frac{x}{2}+2\right)}=e (1+\text{erf}(1))-\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)\sim 2.88060$$

Now, you need to prove that this is correct.

**Such an answer is of absolutely of no use if you do not know or understand the steps.**

Comment: Kindly mention How have you approimated it to 2.88060? although when I subtract these terms I obtain 3.6907